# Installing the windows patch using PSWindowsUpdate

Tags: patch

I am trying to install windows updates using PSWindowsUpdate module in powershell as:

Get-WindowsUpdate -Install -KBArticle 'KB4560960' and hit enter key but    i am not getting any response. Then for confirmation whether the update has been installed or not i used Get-Hotfix command in powershell then it has displayed a list in that list the above update is not their. How to install the specific update using PSWindowsUpdate module in powershell.

Answer (score 0):

After you install the module and then import it you can run the following command:

```
PS C:\Install-WindowsUpdate -MicrosoftUpdate -KBArticleID KB4560960 -AcceptAll -IgnoreReboot
```

It will show the progress of the install or you can type at the PS prompt.
`Get-WUHistory`. Keep in mind, you can't install updates with `PSWindowsUpdates` on remote boxes directly. Will have to use a Task Scheduler—which, in combination with Windows Admin Center, works beautifully.